# How can I prevent my thext from fading after changing background? CSS\HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

I have a problem with some code I grabbed from Codepen, trying to modify to my needs. I want to be able to see "Our Desks" in the top left side of the screen with the background, idk why but when the background changed the span fades. thanks!
here is the Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zm8ps24a/1/

HTML

```
<body> 
    <span class="svc-title"> Our Desks
    </span>
<section id="section-1">
  <div class="hover-link flexboxcenter">   
    <div class="nav-1">
      <a href="#" id="nr-1" class="hvr-underline-from-center">Oldschool Desk</a>
        <div class="bg-1"></div>
      <br>
      <a href="#" id="nr-2" class="hvr-underline-from-center nr-2">Modern Desk</a>
        <div class="bg-2"></div>
      <br>
      <a href="#" id="nr-2" class="hvr-underline-from-center nr-2">Modern Desk Version 2</a>
        <div class="bg-2"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</section>

</body>
```

CSS

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif:400,700);

/* General */



#nr-1:hover + .bg-1,#nr-2:hover + .bg-2{
  opacity:8.0;
}

.flexboxcenter {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.section-1 {

  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.hover-link {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100000;
}

.hover-link .nav-1 {
  z-index: 10000;
}

.hover-link .nav-1 a {
  top:50px;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Droid Serif', serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 50px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}

/* Background classes */

.bg-1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
    background: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1432821596592-e2c18b78144f?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&s=3f9c78df0edb464244bbabb04d1797d8') center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
    height: 200vh;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0.0;
  -webkit-transition-property:opacity;
  transition-property: opacity;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;

}

.bg-2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1421757295538-9c80958e75b0?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&s=3628f27cd5768ece147877e2dd792c6c') center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
    height: 200vh;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: 0.0;
  -webkit-transition-property:opacity;
  transition-property: opacity;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}

/* Hover effect classes */

.new {
  color: white !important;
  opacity: 1 !important;
}

.bla {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

/* Hover Effect Underline From Center by Ian Lunn */

.hvr-underline-from-center {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.hvr-underline-from-center:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 51%;
  right: 51%;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #63A9A9;
  height: 4px;
  -webkit-transition-property: left, right;
  transition-property: left, right;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.hvr-underline-from-center:hover:before, .hvr-underline-from-center:focus:before, .hvr-underline-from-center:active:before {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.svc-title{
  position:relative;
  font-size:20px;
  font-family:'Heebo';
  float:left;
  left:20px;
  top:10px;
  opacity:1;
  color: #a2a3a7;
}
```

JS

```
//Updated

$(function() {
  $('.hover-link .nav-1 a').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
    $('.hover-link .nav-1 a').toggleClass('bla');
  });
});

// Second script - Hover effect on active link

$('.hover-link .nav-1 a').hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass("new");
  },
  function() {
    $(this).removeClass('new');
  });
```

just for saying the base code is by Håkan-Filip Swahn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was struggling for a bit, I fixed it by adding

```css
#section-1 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
}

.svc-title {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Heebo';
    float: left;
    left: 20px;
    top: 10px;
    opacity: 1;
    color: #a2a3a7;
    z-index: 6;
}
```

`#section-1` is the parent of the navigation links

Answer (score 1):

The span disappears because its z-index CSS property is lower than the other elements. Add a higher z-index property value to '.svc-title' and the span will stay visible:

```
.svc-title{
  position:relative;
  font-size:20px;
  font-family:'Heebo';
  float:left;
  left:20px;
  top:10px;
  opacity:1;
  color: #a2a3a7;
  z-index:100001;
}
```

Comment: Nice! thanks it worked, another question please, how can I make the whole text left?
was trying to just change the .flexboxcenter alignment with no success. any ideas?

Comment: Change  `.hover-link .nav-1 a`  from `text-align: center;` to `text-align: left;`

Comment: If you want it all the way left, also change `.flexboxcenter` justify-content and align-items to "left"

Comment: how can I change the whole section color/background? BTW thanks for the help it really helped me!